# I would like to know how a non-admin account can use the Admin SDK

Tags: google-admin-sdk

Sorry if my English is weird.

I would like to know how a non-admin account can use the Admin SDK.
If you have any suggestions, please let me know.

I'm developing an add-on for an elementary school using Google app script.
I want to limit the API by student, teacher, grade, etc. So I need to get the organization information.

There were a few other similar questions, and apparently it would be impossible to try to do it normally.

When using the Admin SDK, Google will display an acceptance confirmation screen to the user.
Once the user agrees, Google gives the app an access token that is valid for a short period of time. I'm thinking that I can do this by using that access token. Is this approach dangerous from a security point of view?

---

I'm sorry for the lack of explanation.

I'm currently developing a google slides add-on for an elementary school.
It's supposed to display a SPA made with vuejs in the sidebar and let you manipulate it.

For example, we can manage a whitelist of organizations that can use this application in advance, and not allow organizations that do not match the whitelist to use it.

If the organization is managed by school unit, access control can be done by domain, but in some areas, the organization is managed by city, so access control by school unit cannot be realized...

Also.We want to do the following if we match the whitelist.

- The functions that can be used by teachers and students are
  different.
- The buttons can be changed depending on the grade level of the
  students.
- Automatically enter student names and class names on slides.

Use an organizational structure to manage the school and students. (https://support.google.com/a/answer/4352075?ref_topic=4390186&hl=en)

We think we can achieve this by using the Admin SDK to get organization information

Comment: First of all, I would need that you explain more detailed what you want to do and the context. Which is your main goal? What limitations do you want to apply to certain users? How do you differentiate users, by the Organizational Units they belong to?

With this information I could understand and help you in a proper way.

Comment: I'm sorry for the lack of explanation.Added information.

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

It is not possible to use [Admin SDK](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-directory) with a non-admin account as Google says in the documentation: *This API gives administrators of Google Workspace domains (including resellers) the ability to manage devices, groups, users, and other entities in their domains.*

However there are two workarounds for your problem, but you would need to use an admin account to configure the scenario.

### Initial approach

- Get the user that is running the application with the class [Session](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session) and the method [getActiveUser](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getActiveUser()) and [getEmail](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/user#getemail): `var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();`
- Get the [organizational unit](https://support.google.com/a/answer/4352075?hl=en) that each user belongs to. With this information you will be able to filter users and display different options in the add-on. The main problem is that you need to use [AdminDirectory.Users.get(userEmail)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-directory#get_user) to get the `organizational unit`, and it needs the following authorization scope: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly`.

### Solution 1

- Create a `Spreadsheet` with all the users that are going to use the add-on and its `organizational unit`
- Use [List all users](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-directory#list_all_users) to get all the users in a domain and write each email in the first column.
- Use `AdminDirectory.Users.get(email).orgUnitPath` to get the `organizational unit` and write it in the next column
- Finally, when users use the add-on, search the email of the active user (`Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()`) in the `Spreadsheet`, take the row number and get the value of the `organizational unit` that is in the second column.

### Solution 2

- Create a [custom admin role](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2406043?hl=en) and assign it to every user that is going to use the add-on. *You must be signed in as a super administrator for this task.* You can do it [here](https://admin.google.com/ac/roles) and select `Users -> Read`,
- Assign the new role to each user [creating a role assignment](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-roles#create_a_role_assignment)
- Finally, users will be able to use `var organization = AdminDirectory.Users.get(email).orgUnitPath`

Comment: Thank you for giving me a concrete way to do this.It is very helpful.

I think I'm going to try using the Solution 2 custom role .
But there is one problem.
It seems that I can only add up to 20 users to one custom role. Is there a workaround for this as well?

Comment: You can only do 20 assignments at a time, but you can repeat the operation as many times as you want. You can also automate the process by listing all the users of the domain and creating the role assignment.

Comment: For documentation purposes if you can, please accept the answer (✓) if that's been helpful to you - it helps other people that have the same issue in the future find the solution too :)